# SAS print variables from cluster analysis

Tags: printing, cluster-computing, sas

I have made a cluster anaysis in SAS using proc cluster.

How do I get SAS to print the number of chosen clusters?
 If I have chosen clusters = 7, I want to print the 7 clusters with the observations that lie in every cluster.

HOw do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OUT=` option on `PROC CLUSTER` to create a SAS data set and use `PROC TREE` to associate the source records into the number of clusters you want.  Then you can sort the result and print by cluster:

```
proc tree data=Tree    /* Data set created by PROC CLUSTER */
          out=New      /* New data set to create */
          nclusters=7  /* Number of clusters you want */
          noprint;
   id idvar;           /* ID variable from PROC CLUSTER */
   copy a b c;         /* Other variables from input data */
run;

proc sort data=new;
   by cluster idvar;
run;

proc print data=new;
   by cluster;
   id cluster;
run;
```

See [this example](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_cluster_sect002.htm) in the SAS documentation for much more info.